# Limit the number of times month name shows

Tags: codeigniter

My list gets the current events from database but shows some months name words multiple time

[image]

> Question How can I make my out put show the month name only once like in image below

[image: [image]]

```
$results = $this->get_events_for_export();

foreach ($results as $result) {

    $date = strtotime($result['event_date']);

    $section->addText(date('M', $date) ."\t". date('d', $date) ."\t". date('D', $date) ."\t". htmlentities($result['event_title']), null, $event_lists);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change it like this :

```
$results = $this->get_events_for_export();

$month_isset = [];
foreach ($results as $result) {

    $date = strtotime($result['event_date']);
    $month_group = date('M', $date);
    $year_group = date('Y', $date);
    if (!isset($month_isset[$year_group][$month_group]))
    {
        $month_isset[$year_group][$month_group] = [];
    }
    else
    {
        $month_group = '';
    }

    $section->addText($month_group ."\t". date('d', $date) ."\t". date('D', $date) ."\t". htmlentities($result['event_title']), null, $event_lists);

}
```